# Get geolocation on Javascript then submit form if validations are met

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

When I press submit, I'm trying to capture the current lat-long and after that I'm running some validations and returning true or false depending on if they are met or not. My problem is that the location function is async and I can't get it to work with my function. I've tried many ways to get this to work, and haven't been successful. I'm hoping you guys could shed some light on what I can do to get it to work like I want. What I want is to capture those coordinates, then execute my save function.

```
$("#save").click(function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        $('#lat-location-end').attr('value', position.coords.latitude);
        $('#lon-location-end').attr('value',position.coords.longitude);
        saveData();
    } function() {
        saveData();
    });
});

function saveData(){
    var odleave = $('#odometer-leave').val();
    var odarrival = $('#odometer-arrival').val();
    var miles = $('#mil').data('mile');

    if (odarrival < odleave){
        alert("Odometer: Arrival must not be less than Odometer: Leave");
        return false;
    }

    if (odleave != miles){
        if (odleave > miles){
            var mile_diff = odleave - miles;
            if (mile_diff > 25){
                if (!confirm("Your leaving mileage exceeds by " + mile_diff + " miles from your last mileage. Do you want to continue?"))
                    return false;
            }
        } else {
            if(!confirm("Mileage entered is less than your last mileage. Are you using a new car?"))
                return false;
        }

        //Return the image
        var sig = signaturePad.toDataURL("image/png");
        sig = sig.split(',')[1];
        $('#sig-data').attr('value', sig);
        return true;
    }
```

Please, I've been having trouble with this all day and I can't find a way to solve this. I asked something similar this morning but I noticed that the question I was asking was the wrong one. I hope this doesn't get me in trouble. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you request the position on loading and then disable the save button until it's available?

Comment: The way the application will be used, it is supposed to capture a location on load, then another location on submit. These are the specifications I was asked for so, I'm capturing coordinates on load and on submit.

Comment: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);` you added `getCurrentPosition(function(position)`,  so `saveData` should work in the `success` function if you include it in. not sure `} function() {check = saveData();` what's this for.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying so many things that I copied one of those failed tries. The main idea is that I wanted to execute `saveData()` in success or error. I will edit the code to better represent this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that I came up with. For this to work you will be needing both files as it is necessary to make everything work.

---

1. semantic.css

---

2. semantic.js

it's either you download it locally from [semantic-ui](https://semantic-ui.com/) or get it on the cdnjs [semantic-ui on cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/semantic-ui).
Hope it helps.

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Get geolocation on Javascript then submit form if validations are met</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://keith-santiago.com/css/semantic.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        div#this-form {

            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="this-form" class="ui raised very padded text container segment">
        <div class="ui form">
        <form class="ui form">
          <div class="field">
            <label>Odometer Arrival</label>
            <input name="odometer-arrival" placeholder="Arrival" type="number">
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <label>Odometer Leave</label>
            <input name="odometer-leave" placeholder="Leave" type="number">
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <div class="ui checkbox">
              <input name="toc"  type="checkbox">
              <label>I agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script
              src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="http://keith-santiago.com/js/semantic.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() { 
        $('.ui.button').click(function() {
        var $form = $('.ui.form');
        var odarrival = parseInt($form.form('get value', 'odometer-arrival'));
        var odleave = parseInt($form.form('get value', 'odometer-leave'));
            $('.ui.form').form({
                fields : {
                        arrival : {
                        identifier : 'odometer-arrival',
                        rules : [{
                            type: 'empty',
                            prompt : "please enter a valid number"
                        }]

                        },
                        leave : {
                        identifier : 'odometer-leave',
                        rules: [ {
                            type : 'empty' 
                            }
                        ]

                    },
                    toc : {
                        identifier : 'toc',
                        rules : [{
                            type : 'checked'
                        }]
                    }   
                }
            });

            if ( $('.ui.form').form('is valid')) {

                if ( odarrival < odleave ) {
                             // this block handles everything before submitting. if the condition are not met it will prevent the form from submitting.
                    return false;
                }
            }   
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: note: that this only focus on the form validation to get your desired result before submission.